# Spring JDBCTemplate exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, jdbctemplate

I use Spring `JDBCTemplate` and I'm suppose to catch `DataAccessException` when problems occurs, but I'm actually facing a `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` which I can't catch in the block, compiler tells me:

> exception PSQLException is never thrown in body

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
 public List<Exe_Resultat> getResultats(Long executionId) {
    try {
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + pojoClasse.getSimpleName() + "WHERE execution_id = ?";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new Object[]{executionId}, this.getRowMapper());
    }
    //I actually get a PSQLException and not a DataAccesException
    catch (DataAccessException e) {
        //Do a thing
    }
}
```

But at the execution of my code I actually get a `PSQLException`.
How can I catch it?

Comment: Change `DataAccessException` to `PSQLException`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: How did you initialized `JdbcTemplate`? Apparently exception translation is off..

Comment: Which exception are you getting... Post the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring translates database specific exceptions to it's own exceptions

Comment: I am a little late to the post but I am facing the same issue. I don't get this accepted answer. Can you please tell me what this means? And what exception to catch